# Chrome extension webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension to analyse requests made on the chrome browser but I can't put it work. The alert never fires.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["background", "tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*/*"],    
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }  
}
```

background.js

```
var callback = function(details) {
    alert("hello");
};
var filter = { "*://*/*" };
var opt_extraInfoSpec = [];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);
```

Why is it my alert not firing?

Comment: use console.log instead, and inspect the background page. I'm fairly certain alert from a background page won't actually display anywhere.

Comment: But if I write to console after that the page reloads and I can't see it. Is there other way to do it? If I use the onBeforeSendHeaders it fires.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your filter is the wrong format - it's not a valid object at all. Addtionally it needs to contain at least the 'url' property. If you wan't all URL's, use this:

```
var filter = {urls: ["<all_urls>"]};
```

Check out this for exact details on the format for the filter: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter

Comment: Just curious to know, where did you find the variable/place-holder name "<all_urls>". I was not able to find it in documentation though.

Comment: There are some extra details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest

Comment: The "<all_urls>" is also documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns

Comment: It took me some time to find the documentation about "<all_urls>" in the chrome docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns